# What is the difference between [^span] and (?!span) in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, code-duplication

I got into a discussion with my co-worker on whether there can be only one correct regular expression for every pattern. I think that two correct regular expressions can occur. Can a pattern be associated with two different, correct regular expressions? Are [^span] and (?!span) the same thing?

Comment: `[^]`: negated set. `(?!)`: negative lookahead

Comment: They do very different things. They're not comparable at all. One is an car, the other a carrot. They're not anywhere near the same thing even though they both start with the same three letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3):

`(?!phrase)` is negative lookahead: from the current point, the following phrase must not be "phrase".

`[^span]` is much different - it matches any *single* character that is not `s`, `p`, `a`, or `n`.

Comment: Thx, I just understood that.